# Why isn't $\int\sin(ix)~dx$ equal to $i\cos(ix)+C$ ?

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry, complex-numbers, indefinite-integrals

I was playing around with imaginary numbers, and I tried to solve $$\int\sin(ix)~dx$$ and ended up getting  $$i\cos(ix)+C$$

But apparently the answer is $$i\cosh(x)+C$$

I was just wondering, is this correct? And what does the "$h$" stand for/mean? Where did it even come from. Thanks in advance.

Comment: See [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_function#Standard_algebraic_expressions) for the meaning of $\cosh$. Note that $i\cos(ix)=i\cosh(x)$.

Comment: thank you! makes much more sense, I should really get more aquainted with standard expression, appreciated :).

Comment: Why did you surmise that the two answers are different in the first place ?

Comment: @Lucian The law in the land of Mathematics is "unequal until proven equal" ;)

Comment: because I didn't know what hyperbolic functions were in the first place @Lucian

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here are two useful definitions / relations

$$\cosh(x) = \frac{e^x + e^{-x}}{2}$$

$$\cos(x) = \frac{e^{ix} + e^{-ix}}{2}$$

Using these definitions you can see that

$$\cos(ix) = \frac{e^{i(ix)} + e^{-i(ix)}}{2} = \frac{e^{-x} + e^x}{2} = \cosh (x)$$

So you *did* get the same answer, but you just had it in a different form.

Comment: oh, I thought I totally got it wrong, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Using
$$
\sin(x)=\frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2i}\quad\text{and}\quad\cos(x)=\frac{e^{ix}+e^{-ix}}{2}
$$
we have
$$
\cos(ix)=\cosh(x)\quad\text{and}\quad\sin(ix)=i\sinh(x)
$$
Thus,
$$
\begin{align}
\sin(x+iy)
&=\sin(x)\cos(iy)+\cos(x)\sin(iy)\\
&=\sin(x)\cosh(y)+i\cos(x)\sinh(y)\\
\end{align}
$$
and
$$
\begin{align}
\cos(x+iy)
&=\cos(x)\cos(iy)-\sin(x)\sin(iy)\\
&=\cos(x)\cosh(y)-i\sin(x)\sinh(y)\\
\end{align}
$$